# Conditionally set viewport for iPhone4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, css

I was hoping to just use,

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=false" />
```

and then call different style sheets based on the width. The only problem is that the iPhone4 reports a width of 320px even tho its 640px. How would I conditionally set the content width to 640px for iPhone4s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into `Media Queries` to achieve what you are asking.

Here are some really good articles related to building responsive, fluid, multi-device websites:

**Smashing Magazine's 'How to use Media Queries'**:
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

**A-List Apart article on Fluid Grids:**
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

And, **Smashing Magazine article on Responsive web Design** (*references A-List Apart's article on same subject*):
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/